Classloader Leak when using java 7 and tomcat 6?
I have a Tomcat 6 instance running on Java 7. While monitoring the service with JMX and Prometheus, I observed that the jvm_classes_loaded metric increases significantly, reaching nearly 500k.


I am unsure about the cause of this issue. Can anyone guide me on how to detect the root of the problem?

As it goes back down to the same value (close to zero): This does not look like a leak. Rather like Garbage Collection doing it's job. What exactly is your problem in this long EOL'ed environment? If it's just the number of allocated classes: Provide less memory to the process, and GC will kick in sooner. But as there's no leak, no general change can be expected.
